# pyspark failing to run query in parallel using foreach

Tags: pyspark

I have a function that generates different query and executes them and writes data into different tables. I want to parallelize this.
Here is an example:

```
def build_and_execute_sql(item):
    gen_sql = 'insert overwrite table schema.table_d_{} select * from ...'.format(item)
    spark.sql(gen_sql)


sc = spark.sparkContext
lst = ['products', 'orders', 'deliveries']
rdd = sc.parallelize(lst)
rdd.foreach(build_and_execute_sql)
```

when I execute this, this fails with no specific error. My goal is to execute this in parallel.
I have about 12 such queries that are generated and are executed.
I tried to play around with `rdd.formach(build_execute_sql).collect()`, but nothing really works.
Any pointers?? wondering why would `foreach` fail?
I'm familiar with multiprocessing, but wondering if there is a clean way to do it in pyspark itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try python `multiprocessing` instead:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

lst = ['products', 'orders', 'deliveries']

with ThreadPool(3) as p:
    p.map(build_and_execute_sql, lst)
```

Comment: I'm familiar with multiprocessing, but wondering if there is a clean way to do it in pyspark itself.

Comment: @user3327034, not the way you're trying to do. You can't call spark in foreach or map...  this parallelization does not depend. I used `ThreadPool` in my experience and it works fine, you need only to take care of the resources and how many processes you can use.